# Why does it say that somebody else passed a review audit that I passed?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

I just passed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16350724). I clicked Recommend Deletion and the "Congratulations! You passed!" message showed up as it usually does when passing review audits. But the problem is that when I refreshed the page, it doesn't say that I passed it but it says that another user passed it:

[image]

I also checked my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4284627/donald-duck?tab=activity&sort=reviews) and it doesn't say anything about that audit there:

[image]

Also, I can't see the answer that the audit was on since the answer was deleted (it says "answer not found"), although I usually can see posts that I got as audits, even if they are deleted.

What's going on here? Why doesn't it say that I passed that review audit?

Comment: *"although I usually can see posts that I got as audits, even if they are deleted"* - Are you sure? I certainly couldn't. They're only visible during the audit, not afterwards. Other than that: weirdness. Like both you and this other person got the exact same audit, and they completed it first or last depending on how the system copes with concurrent modifications.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I'm sure. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15654560) is an example of an audit I passed on a deleted post. To prove that I can see the post, here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrvJ.png

Comment: Well then, I stand corrected and am amazed. EDIT: thinking about it, there are certain rules to when you can see deleted content or not that have been updated recently. Probably you can see deleted content sometimes, not always.

Comment: There is a known race condition that shows the same audit to two users. Only one of them get their action recorded but the user that didn't make it into the review table will get a new audit within the next couple of reviews. This situation is more likely to happen when you review with the same tag filter applied by a couple of users. When running out of available review tasks AND the users are kind of in sync for when they are up for an audit, they are much more likely to get the same audit. Happened a couple of times between me and other regulars of SOCVR during a close vote event.

Comment: @rene You're right, I just tested and I got [another audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16351255) 3 reviews later, and this time, it worked just fine.

Comment: @Gimby: Since a year or two ago, all reviewers can always see deleted posts used for audits *in the review queue*. That is, audits can always be referred back to for later consideration.